# Extracting a number from a text string

Tags: mysql, text, numbers, extract

when returning a result I have a text string which includes a hyperlink.That hyperlink includes a video id number which is what I want to ultimately extract.
The text string can vary in length so the count of letters before and after the number I want to extract varies.
Here is an example:

```
> Hello Mrs. Sinatra, Here is an email that supports practices for Danielson Domain:https://www.pd360.com/#resources/videos/330 (Utilize Effective Strategies - 11:23)
```

The number I would want to extract is 330, it always follows; `/videos/###`

Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest splitting on a slash (/) and grab the last subscript

Comment: Could you show an example at all please?

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is same you can use `substring_index` something as

```
mysql> select substring_index('https://www.pd360.com/#resources/videos/330','/videos/',-1) as id ;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 330 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you have more strings after the `/videos/330` and if they are separated by `' '` then you may use as

```
mysql> 
select 
 substring_index(
    substring_index(
      'pd360.com/index.html#resources/videos/5334 (Using Manipulatives in Algebra - 8:56)"','/videos/',-1
     ),' ',1
  ) as id ;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 5334 |
+------+
```

You may change the hard coded string with your column name in the table something like

```
select 
substring_index(substring_index(col_name,'/videos/',-1),' ',1) as id
from table_name
```

Comment: I may not have explained clearly however, that the '330' varies.  So its not just the 330 I need to extract, its any number that follows '/videos/???'

Comment: Yes it will be any number after `/videos/###`, so the above query will return any number after `/videos/`

Comment: All I get if I use the above query is the 330 result, nothing else changes.  For example, in the following text string, I would want to extract the '5334' number; "Hello Mr. Castro, Here is a resource that may provide you additional ideas on using algebra tiles in your mathematics instruction. Ms. Dobson https://www.pd360.com/index.html#resources/videos/5334 (Using Manipulatives in Algebra - 8:56)"

Comment: So you mean there could be some other strings are the number ? and if so those strings are separated by one space after the number ? Like you have `videos/5334 (Using Manipulatives`

Comment: The text string varies in length and content, however there is always a number after the word 'videos/(insert number here)'  That is the number I want to extract.  for example: " https://www.pd360.com/#resources/videos/281" < I want to extract 281, "Hello teachers, Here is a video resource that focuses on designing engaging lessons with opening hooks, direct and guided instruction and closure. https://www.pd360.com/#resources/videos/636 (Designing Lessons for Engagement - Secondary - 7:38)" < I want to extract 636

Comment: select 
substring_index(substring_index(col_name,'/videos/',-1),' ',1) as id
from table_name  < This one worked, thank you so much.